# Repeating events on onBindviewHolder components

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-viewholder

Sorry I know I repeated this question.When I changed the text on a `cardview` the text is repeating to another.Text `textview` differ by its position.Also when I clicked a component the `onclicklistener` repeating in some another.Please help me to solve the problem..

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        Context context=null;
        if(!(mDataset.get(position).getmText1().length()<=3&&mDataset.get(position).getmText1() == null && mDataset.get(position).getmText1().equals("#EE"))) {
            Log.e("Hello",mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
            holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mDataset.get(position).getmText1()));
            holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.qua.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDataset.get(position).setmText2(holder.qua.getText().toString());
                    if (!(mDataset.get(position).getmText2().length() == 0 && mDataset.get(position).getmText2().equals("0"))) {
                        holder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.set.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.qua.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.text.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
                    } else holder.text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

[image]
**[image]**
The pic when  I enter text.
[image]
The pic when I scrolled has the same text I entered!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the normal behavior of the RecyclerView, due to its recycling mechanism. You should reset the View's visibility if the condition is not met. For example:

```
if(yourConditionIsTrue) {
   yourView.setVisibality(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   yourView.setVisibality(View.GONE);
}
```

In your case move the condition out side of your click listener:

```
     @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
                Context context=null;

               holder.set.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               holder.qua.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                if (!(mDataset.get(position).getmText2()==null && mDataset.get(position).getmText2().equals("0"))) {
                                holder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
holder.text.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());
                            } else {
                                holder.text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }

                if(!(mDataset.get(position).getmText1().length()<=3&&mDataset.get(position).getmText1() == null && mDataset.get(position).getmText1().equals("#EE"))) {
                    Log.e("Hello",mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
                    holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mDataset.get(position).getmText1()));
                    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            holder.set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.qua.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                mDataset.get(position).setmText2(holder.qua.getText().toString());

                                holder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.set.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                holder.qua.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                holder.text.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());

                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: My condition is thar,the text  entered not a null or zero.But I applied this condition and its not working

Comment: I edited program in my question on the basis of your answer.

Comment: Its working.But the problem is when I scrolled down and up the text  entered gets gone and places **small text**

Comment: Its worked when add `holder.text.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2())` this in first `if`..Thanks

Comment: Please approve my edit other wise others cannot see the answer

Comment: I approved it. This is frequently happen problem, I hope it helps some others people.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because OnCreateViewHolder not repeat on every time of cell creation. RecyclerView call it only on specific time then repeat these views.

Solution is to make an object in the class of your Datalist, save data in that object whenever EditText gets changed by position and on every OnBindViewHolder call get that data by position and reload the editText otherwise keep it empty.

Comment: I did it in my question and I edited it..I made a object in my data list..mDataset.get(position).getmText2()

Comment: You have to save the data of all object that are dynamic and retain or reload it in onBindViewHolder.